# New Admin Bar Not Functioning

Tags: admin-bar

With WP 3.1, as we all know, the admin bar is a new feature on your blog when you are logged in as an administrator, but for some reason on my theme, the admin bar is not there. In it's place is a grey bar about 30 pixels tall (matching my pages background color).

What could be hiding it? If it's useful, the theme is at wphax.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `footer.php` and make sure it contains `<?php wp_footer(); ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to making sure `footer.php` contains `<?php wp_footer(); ?>`, I had a situation where, when designing a custom theme, the bar disappeared. After undoing some of my code changes and not getting joy, I ended up doublechecking that the checkboxes for the bar were checked under "Profile," and then I had to log out and then log back in to get it to reappear.

This was with stock version 3.1 and an in-development theme.